# newsletter with export email to csv and import from csv features

Tags: emails

i had use simplenews before, but there is no function to export or import email to csv file.

anyone know any module have such functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do that:

1. Install [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) (you probably have this installed already).
2. Install [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module.
3. Create a new view that will show either "Simplenews subscriber" or "Simplenews subscription".
4. Add a new display of "Data export" type to that view. There you can choose the format (`.csv`, `.doc`, `.txt`, etc.) and configure other settings. Don't forget to set "Attach to" value to the page display you created in step #3.